# How to add custom session data in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function session_input()
{
  $session_value = $this->input->post('welcome');

  $this->session->set_userdata('name', $session_value);

  echo "<a href='".  base_url()."/index.php/contact/session_output'> go to </a>";

  echo "your session has been save " ;
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: @rahul yeah.. its correct

Comment: @Arun ok will use that

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieving Session Data**

Any piece of information from the session array is available using the following function:

```
$this->session->userdata('item');
```

Where item is the array index corresponding to the item you wish to fetch. For example, to fetch the session ID you will do this:

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

Note: The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are trying to access does not exist.

**Adding Custom Session Data**

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);

$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes correct

$session_value = $this->input->post('welcome');

if($this->session->set_userdata('name', $session_value)){

echo "your session has been save";

}

you can read more about it here -> 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score -1):

if its single value session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session_name', 'session_value');
```

if its multiple value session:

```
$array_name = array('value1','value2','value3');
$this->session->set_userdata('session_name',$array_name);
```

array along with key

```
$array_name = array('key_name1'=>'value1','key_name2'=>'value2','key_name3'=>'value3');
$this->session->set_userdata('session_name',$array_name);
```

to get the session value

```
$var = $this->session->userdata('session_name');
```